# set onclick attribute with dynamic arguments

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to create dynamic list of hrefs using JavaScript, for that I need the link to execute some function each time the user click on the href BUT with different arguments.

**Code:** What I tried so far is this!

```js
    for(var k in LIST_OF_ARGUMENTS){
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.setAttribute("href","#");
            // K here is the argument of myFunction 
            a.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction("+k+")")
            a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(k))
            li.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Have you never heard of `a.onclick = ...`? Or better still `a.addEventListener(...);`? Remember to lock the scope of `k` though, otherwise it won't work as you expect.

Comment: @nietthedarkabsol but the OP is creating a string and setting it as the onclick string attribute, `k` is creating different strings each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes, hence the need to scope `k` appropriately.

Comment: @farhawa to should post an example that runs, right now it looks like it should work, even though you should not be setting handlers through attributes

Comment: You could just set a [data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to your `k` value and then in your `myFunction` access it to get your value, instead of trying to create multiple onclick values

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I tried the `a.onclick=...` and it run the function without clicking on the link... Any answer please?

Comment: @farhawa see my answer for how to run `myFunction` with different arguments only when user clicks each link.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol See my answer, I still don't understand what you mean that k needs to be scoped correctly, OP is not creating closures, just strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work, making `k` the correct variable for the onclick event.

If you don't create the onclick handler separately but instead do `a.onlick = myFunction(k);` inside the for loop, `k` will be the last value of `k` in the for loops iteration for each `a` element (every click event will fire the same function using the same value of `k`).

```
function doClick(a, k) {
   a.onclick = function() {
      myFunction(k);
   }
};
for (var k in LIST_OF_ARGUMENTS) {
   var li = document.createElement("li");
   var a = document.createElement("a");
   doClick(a, k);
   a.setAttribute("href", "#");
   // K here is the argument of myFunct
   a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(k))
   li.appendChild(a);
}
```

Comment: What you are saying is true but it's only a problem if you set the onclick to a function that shares a closure. The OP did was not making use of closures in their handlers, their handler is a string that gets evaled by the browser

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function myFunction(value) {
    alert(value);
  }
</script>

<ul id="my-list"></ul>

<script>
  var args = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  };

  for (var arg in args) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.setAttribute('onclick', 'myFunction(' + args[arg] + ')');
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arg));
    li.appendChild(a);
    document.getElementById('my-list').appendChild(li);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to simplify event handling.

```
ul.onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    // check here if it's your link 
    console.log(target.htef);
};
```

So your full code could be somthing like:

```
var args = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    ul = document.querySelector(".list");

for (var k in args) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var a = document.createElement("a");

    a.setAttribute("href", "#" + k);
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(k))
    li.appendChild(a);

    ul.appendChild(li);
}

ul.onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    console.log(target.htef);
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ac498es0/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, you just weren't appending your nodes to the document.

```js
window.myFunction = function(val) {
  console.log('Clicked ' + val);
}
var LIST_OF_ARGUMENTS =  ['a','b', 'c', 'd'];
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
// Shouldn't use `for in` with arrays, this is just 
for (var k=0; k < LIST_OF_ARGUMENTS.length; k++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href", "#");
  // K here is the argument of myFunction 
  a.setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction(" + k + ")")
  a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(LIST_OF_ARGUMENTS[k]))
  li.appendChild(a);
  ul.appendChild(li)
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```